# How to show heatmaps on all visible elements at once?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I was testing [Heatmaps SDK](https://heatma.ps), and I wanted to know if there is a setting or a way to show heatmaps on all the visible elements at one time? Currently I can view one element at a time like below.

This is my setup and below are pictures of the results:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    UIViewController *rootVC = _window.rootViewController;
    self.window = [[HMUIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = rootVC;

    heatmaps = [[Heatmaps alloc] init];
    heatmaps.showDebug = YES;
    heatmaps.showMenu = YES;
    [heatmaps start];

    //...

    return YES;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you may only see the heatmap for one element at a time.