# Visual analytics tools for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sdk, analytics

I am used to testing my websites with interaction analytic tools like [crazy egg](http://www.crazyegg.com/), which enable me to see how people interact with my site, where they touch it and what visual attracts them.

Do you know any SDK's or tools that will enable me to view similar analytics for my iPhone or iPad, iOS app?  I don't really want to write it myself. Just looking for a simple SDK with minimum setup to make it work.

NOTE: I'am not talking about flurry, or localytics, those are plain statistical analytic tools I need visual tools that measure or show user behavior.

Comment: https://heatma.ps/ is one I hear about often these days.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem. I found and use [heatmaps SDK](https://heatma.ps). This tool lets you view how people use your application by showing you the heatmap (places where they touch it).

It also gave me pretty great info about the gestures people make when they use my app. I didn't have any gestures implemented, and it discovered if people try to scroll the screen or pinch a photo. I was surprised to find out that people thought they could just swipe to another screen instead of tapping on the button. Lesson learned.

Here is the screen shot of the heatmap. You can also see my question [How to show heatmaps on all visible elements at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8047958/1029364) where I posted my heatmap when I did tests.

[image: heatma.ps SDK]